# Object method performing different when used in conjunction with another method

Tags: symfony, twig

In my Twig template, I wanted to get a count of my active participants and my checked in participants for a certain tournament.
So I wrote this code

```
<p>{{ tournament.getcheckedinparticipants.count }}</p>
<p>{{ tournament.getactiveparticipants.count }}</p>
```

However, this returns

```
1
1
```

While it should return

```
1
10
```

The crazy thing is, when I only enter the second method

```
<p>{{ tournament.getactiveparticipants.count }}</p>
```

it does actually return

```
10
```

What the hell is going on? Is there some kind of interference I'm unaware of?

EDIT: It appears to be something with the order of the functions executing. If I do it the other way around, the correct values are returned. I've found a small workaround FOR NOW where I assign the results to a variable, and later on use the correct order for displaying them.

```
{% set actives = tournament.getactiveparticipants.count %}
{% set checkedins = tournament.getcheckedinparticipants.count %}

<p>{{ checkedins }}</p>
<p>{{ actives }}</p>
```

EDIT2: These are my model methods

```
/**
 * Get participants
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getParticipants()
{
    return $this->participants;
}

public function getActiveParticipants() {
    $participants = $this->getParticipants();

    foreach ($participants as $key => $participant) {
        if ($participant->getCancelDate()) {
            unset($participants[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $participants;
}

public function getCheckedinParticipants() {
    $participants = $this->getParticipants();

    foreach ($participants as $key => $participant) {
        if (!$participant->getCheckedin()) {
            unset($participants[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $participants;
}
```

Comment: Could you dump tournament in your view and show us the result? `{{ dump(tournament) }}`

Comment: Both getCheckedinParticipants and getActiveParticipants are public functions, so they don't show up in a dump of tournament.

Comment: Ho ok, and what are they return? An integer? I don't really undertsand `.count`

Comment: They return an array.

Comment: Ok, did you try: `{{ tournament.getactiveparticipants|length }}`

Comment: Still `1 1`. I've also tried dumping both arrays, but they appear to be idential, even have the same #id for the Persistent Collection object..

Comment: problem seems to be in your model...

Comment: Not exactly, because, like I said, when I use the getactiveparticipants function WITHOUT the getcheckedinparticipants function, it returns the correct value

Comment: Ok wow, even more strange. When I switch the functions around (so get active first, then the checkedins) it returns the correct values.

Comment: I've found a small "workaround". I execute the functions in the opposite direction (so active first, then checkedins) and assign them to a variable. Then later on I can use the variables in the correct order. Very strange bug though..

Comment: Consider posting your tournament.get methods.  I suspect you have some kind of caching going on which is causing them to return the same array.

Comment: Do your `getActiveParticipants`/`getCheckedinParticipants` just return the array directly or do they perform any logic?

Comment: I've edited in my methods :)